# How to copy bucket in amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm really sick of amazon ability to clone a bucket. They don't offer bucket renaming and they don't offer a good way to copy bucket with dozen of thousands files in it. Is there a way that take seconds to minutes instead of hours?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us by which means you are trying to copy files? (Web interface, command line, 3rd party application? Within a VPC, etc?)

Comment: I'm using the aws command http://timkay.com/aws/ I have search around but all I get is just worse solution.

Comment: I commented on the link you quoted. The issue is these solutions still rely on the client doing the listing and submit request one per file. Dozen of thousands of requests to amazon and back to my machine is by no mean speedy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily clone a bucket by using [sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). (First create the bucket you want to clone it to):

`aws s3 sync --quiet s3://[bucket-old] s3://[bucket-new]`

Tip: use the `--dryrun` flag to see what you're doing first (and break it off when it looks good or else you have to wait for your thousands of files to finish listing)

Comment: Thanks for this. But it is still slow as it need to submit as many requests as number of files I have. I'm looking for a solution with least amount of requests and everything happen on S3 itself instead.

Comment: The command in my answer does let everything take place on S3 itself, but it does indeed output a line per file. You could speed it up by adding `--quiet` as a parameter (I've updated my answer).

Comment: This sync doesn't even sync permissions. And it still makes a request per file. I have a lot of files so it's still a lot of requests, which make it painfully slow. Running it from an EC2 instance alleviate the issue. But in the end the permissions are still not synced. What's a pain.

Comment: Since I only have single type of permissions for all my files, I'm able to use --acl to set the permissions problem now. Seem like running it from EC2 with some parameters is the best thing available right now. Thanks @Maneating Koala, I would have sworn on these Amazon bastards without your help :)